# Starting the multi-files upload by CTRL-C/CTRL-V on web-page

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, copy-paste

There are i would like to do:
1) to select several files at my computer (by mouse or keyboard)
2) to press CTRL-C (copy selected files info to clipboard)
3) to press CTRL-V at focused HTML-element (e.g. DIV) to start copying selected files to server (of cours, in first i have to take info about clipboard content after CTRL-V)
How can i do it?
Thank you!

I have read about:
1) paste-event, but this method can paste plain text or image from clipboard.
2) drag-drop events, they are good for me, but they are only mouse controlled, i want to use CTRL-C/CTRL-V

Comment: that is possible only on Mozilla browser, so would just let it go